# Turn on/off WiFi via Mute switch

Tags: ipad, wifi

I have jailbroken my iPad for firewall, XBMC and some development things only.

I didn't know before that on the right-hand side near the volume buttons is a switch. In settings I have two options for it: lock screen rotation or mute. I don't need either of them, but I've got an idea on my mind - how about to turn on/off WiFi with this switch? (To save some battery.)

Is there a mod or something that lets me do so?

Answer (score 1):

## [Activator](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/libactivator)

**You could try a custom action using Activator**, set up to toggle WiFi when the Silent switch is double-toggled.

I am currently not jailbroken myself (running iOS 7) and haven't used Activator for a while, but I remember that there is an option to activate an action by double-toggling the mute switch, as can be seen in the screenshot below.

There may be a way to activate it using a single toggle, but I am not able to find this out myself right now. Despite this, a double-toggle returns the toggle to its original point, meaning that **you could use the toggle for WiFi and orientation/mute at the same time** (a single toggle doesn't activate the double-toggle action).

[image: Toggle Mute Switch Twice]

Comment: Nicy try, better than nothing. I'm afraid that my switch can handle fast double switching with my huge fingers ;P
thank you for help, I'll test it for now, but still searching for something that just replaces the functionality.